# This returns the records I want, but not the size/count/length like I would expect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, arel

I have the following scope on my model.  I created it so I could get a list of parent objects that have children that match the some_id_on_child value 123.  This seems to return the right records.

```
scope :light, joins(:children).where(children: { some_id_on_child: 123 }).group('parents.id')
```

However, when I ask for the count/length/size instead of returning the number of records that were returned above, it returns the number of children that match the criteria per parent.

```
Parent.light.size
```

I end up with this kind of output..

```
...
12984 => 5
12398 => 5
12398 => 6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `group` bit is what is causing the result when you add `count`.  Rails is doing some magic and converting `size` to `count` as well.  If you don't mind returning all the results you could append `.all.size` and should do it.  Or drop the `group` bit and add `.distinct('parent_id').count`.